# Laravel - Eloquent Construction - Group By through Pivot Table

Tags: laravel

please help me construct an eloquent query. i have this tables:

```
Attendances
id | member_id
1  | 1
2  | 2
3  | 3
4  | 4
5  | 5

Members
id | name
1  | Joe
2  | Jane
3  | David
4  | May
5  | John

Positions
id | position_name
1  | art
2  | singer
3  | dancer

member_position
member_id | position_id
1         | 2 
1         | 1
1         | 3
2         | 1
2         | 2
3         | 3
4         | 1
4         | 3
5         | 3
```

from the Attendances table, i need to get how many attendant per position are present.

Desired result:

```
Art: 3
Singer: 2
Dancer: 4
```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to get the result i wanted using the codes below:

```
$member_ids = Attendance::pluck('member_id');

$positions = Position::whereHas('members', function($query) use($member_ids){
                 return $query->whereIn('id', $member_ids);
             })->get();

$datas = [];

foreach($positions as $position){
  $position_id = $position->id;

  $subdata = Attendance::whereHas('member.positions', function($query) use($position_id){
              return $query->where('id', $position_id);
            })->get();

  $datas[] = ['position' => $position->position_name, 'count' => $subdata->count()];
}

return view('viewfile', compact('datas'));
```

and on my blade file:

```
@foreach($datas as $data)
 <td>{{ $data['position'] }}</td>
 <td>{{ $data['count'] }}</td>
@endofreach
```

hope this would help someone in the future.

(i just answered my question because it seems that i cannot delete it, apologies to those who viewed and didnt find it interesting to answer)